# Mass update doesnt work in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, interface, interceptor, proxy

I am using bulk action feature in admin, on catalog page when am trying to update attribute am getting below error

> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot
>   instantiate interface
>   Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\ConfigInterface in
>   /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116

Any smart idea what can be wrong
I tried

> cache clean, remove generated code, compile di

but nothing helps

Comment: Are you using redis? If so try `redis-cli flushall`

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/upgrade_51431.html

Comment: but am not updating my magento, this exist only when am using mass update

Comment: By the way I already that :(

Comment: try to remove the generated directory and try `di:compile` again

Comment: in what deploy-mode are you?

Comment: am on developer mode